# For Each in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I want to display the largest date of a note by account number. There's no way to tie account notes to a specific order in our database, so my report will only display recent notes. I need to find the most recent note, by account. Everything I've seen online says to Group By the account *first* then use `MAXIMUM()`. But the report has many suppressed lines that create blank groups/lines and litter the displayed data.

Can I suppress group headers and line spacing when all records in a group are suppressed? Doing this would let me group by account and solve the `MAXIMUM()` problem This would be useful for lots of the reports we run.

If not, can I use `MAXIMUM() or a similar function that doesn't include formal groups? Using this by itself returns the largest value within the entire report, which is useless.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own SQL Command for Crystal to use.

Whenever you make a report, it uses a SQL Query behind the scenes (which you can view under Database -> Show SQL Query) but you can also write them yourself. Try writing a custom SQL command and adding it via the Database Expert. This will allow you to filter out many of the suppressed lines and perform omissions that Crystal wouldn't be able to evaluate.

From there it's just a matter of understanding SQL and writing the query to match your databases and filtering needs.